# Pattern-Matching Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

This is slide from class at my University, it about Pattern-Matching Algotithm..
 [image]

And I try to code it in Java below;

```
            // Get values for both the text T1,T2 ... Tn and the pattern P1 P2 ... Pm
            String[] T = {"Java", "is", "too", "delicious", ", Dr.Java", "is", "confrim!"};
            String[] P = { "is", "too"};
            // Get values for n and m, the size of the text and the pattern, respectively
            int n = T.length;
            int m = P.length;
            // Set k1 the starting location for the attempted match, to 1
            int k = 0;

            // While(k<=(n-m+1))do
            while (k <= (n - m + 1) - 1) {
                    // Set the value of i to 1
                    int i = 0;
                    // Set the value of Mismatch NO
                    boolean Mismatch = true; // Not found (true - NO)

                    // While both (i<=m) and (Mismatch = NO) do
                    while ((i <= m - 1) && (Mismatch)) { // if Not found (true - NO)
                            // if Pi != Tk+(i-1) then
                            if (P[i].equals(T[k])) { // if Found(true)
                                    // Set Mismatch to YES
                                    Mismatch = false; // Found (false - YES)
                                    // Else
                            } else {
                                    // Increment i by 1 (to move to the next character)
                                    i = i + 1;
                            }
                            // End of the loop
                    }
                    // If mismatch = NO then
                    if (!Mismatch) { // if Found (false - YES)
                            // Print the message 'There is a match at position'
                            System.out.print("There is a match at position ");
                            // Print the value of k
                            System.out.println(k);
                    }
                    // Increment k by 1
                    k = k + 1;
                    // Enf of the loop
            }
            // Stop, we are finished
```

But I have a question! why in pseudo code version, check if P not equal T ? I think it would rather to be check if P equal T (How it difference with my version? , sorry for my terrible English)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a translation mistake at the inner while

```
while ((i <= m - 1) && (Mismatch)) { // if Not found (true - NO)
```

In pseudo code it was said to be `Mismatch=no` which would be `!Mismatch`

This resulted in the case that you had to invert the inner if statement.

Comment: thanks! but how I can fix it? I try to change && (!Mismatch) and !(P[i].equals(T[k])) but it doesn't work ..

Comment: @Smile Did you set mismatch to true in the if statement block?

Comment: @Smile Did you initialize the mismatch with the opposite value?

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo code essentially checks from every point a match could possibly begin in T (`1 <= k <= n-m+1`), loops and checks that the substring of T from k to k+m-1 matches P. So as soon as it finds one mismatched letter, it stops checking the substring, and increments k (to check from the next position). That conditional (`T[k+i-1] != P[i]`) is the breaking condition for the inner loop, and the boolean to flag that from the current starting position `k`, there is no match.

Note that this algorithm has complexity `O(nm)` which is slow. There are smarter algorithms that can search in linear time, like KMP.